# Which tag to use for social media icons

Tags: html, accessibility

Which tags should wrap a social media icon in respect to accessibility?
I have this div, containing social media icons:

```
  <div class="social-media-container" role="region">
      <div>
        <ion-icon name="logo-facebook"><a href="#"></a></ion-icon>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ion-icon name="logo-twitter"><a href="#"></a></ion-icon>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ion-icon name="logo-instagram"><a href="#"></a></ion-icon> 
      </div>
    </div>
```

Wrapped in a div with an aria-ole are three social media icons. Which tag should I use for them in respect to accessibility?

Comment: You don't need to use any special tag for accessibility. The `<a>` should contain actual text that describes where the user is going along with a valid `href` value. https://usability.yale.edu/web-accessibility/articles/links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't a specific tag which should be used to wrap icons. However, you can do some things to make your icons accessible, as from [Font Awesome docs](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/other-topics/accessibility):

> If your icons have semantic meaning, you’ll need to manually add a few
> things so that your icon is appropriately accessible:
>
> - aria-hidden="true" attribute.
> - Provide a text alternative inside a  (or similar) element. Also include appropriate CSS to visually hide the element while keeping it accessible to assisitive technologies.
> - title attribute on the icon to provide a tooltip for sighted mouse users.

According to that, your HTML would be this way:

```
<div class="social-media-container" role="region">
  <div>
    <a href="#">
       <ion-icon name="logo-facebook" aria-hidden="true" title="Visit our Facebook webpage"></ion-icon>
       <span class="sr-only">Visit our Facebook webpage</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#">
       <ion-icon name="logo-twitter" aria-hidden="true" title="Visit our Twitter webpage"></ion-icon>
       <span class="sr-only">Visit our Twitter webpage</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#">
       <ion-icon name="logo-instagram" aria-hidden="true" title="Visit our Instagram webpage"></ion-icon>
       <span class="sr-only">Visit our Instagram webpage</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As proposed at https://www.w3schools.com/icons/, I would use the `<i>` tag following by a descriptive class like `i-facebook`

In your case, this would looks like:

```html
 <div class="social-media-container" role="region">
      <div>
       <i class="i-facebook"><a href="#"></a></i>
      </div>
      <div>
        <i class="i-twitter"><a href="#"></a></i>
      </div>
      <div>
        <i class="i-instagram"><a href="#"></a></i>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Class names are absolutely useless for accessibility. The `i` element is for styling text, it is wildly unsuitable for including icons. W3School's advice is, in general, awful. Avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

there is no specific tag for social media icons however you can always go on fontawesome.com to get some of the best icons. All you need to do is:

- Go to fontawesome.com
- Search for the icon you are looking for in the search box on top left
  corner.
- Click on the icon you like the best for you work.
- Click on "Start using this icon" button that appears beside your
  chosen icon.
- The HTML code appears for the respective icon, just copy the code in
  your html file under a  tag (though using  isn't
  necessary).
- You are all set to use the icon.

Comment: The HTML that generates has absolutely no accessibility features whatsoever … so you've recommended completely changing the way that the OP loads their icons without addressing their problem at all.